# Javascript dynamic variable for id #

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, dynamic

I have a working JS codes (when you click on a cell with id#, it will highlight the cell and the associated row in another table) in the same PHP file and I wish to move it to external JS .js file so that I can re-use for other PHP files.

```
<td class="text-center" id="grid_B9">Click me to highlight me and other row</td>
<tr id="E3"><td class="text-center"></td>

$page_script .= "$(document).ready(function(){";
foreach ($storage_position_used as $storage_id => $positions)
    // add class 'success' to table row
    foreach ($positions as $storage_position_used) {
        $page_script .= '$("#grid_'.$storage_position_used.'").click(function(){';
        $page_script .= '$("#grid_'.$storage_position_used.'").toggleClass("success");';
        $page_script .= '$("#'.$storage_position_used.'").toggleClass("success");';
        $page_script .= "});";
    }
$page_script .= "});";
```

My recode in JS external file so far, but is not working. There IS highlight but always on the same cell.

```
$storage_position_used = storage_position_array($storage_id, 'used');
$page_script .= 'highlight_specimen_row('.json_encode($storage_position_used[$storage_id]).');';   
// highlight_specimen_row(["E2","A3","A1","C1","B1","D1","C9"]);

function highlight_specimen_row (positions_used) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < positions_used.length; i++) {
        var grid_position_id = "grid_"+positions_used[i];
        var position_id = positions_used[i];

        $('#'+grid_position_id).click(function() {
            $('#'+grid_position_id).toggleClass("success");
            $('#'+position_id).toggleClass("success");
        });
    }
});
}
```

I believe I declared my dynamic variable (grid_position_id  and position_id ) wrongly.

Comment: the `$document.ready` inside your function doesn't make sense.

Comment: you whole logic is far too complicated. Rather make a selector by custom classname, then refer to the object via `this`

Comment: I believe the first thing you should do, with they way you've done it, is to log inside the for to see if it runs correct, can do you do this and comment back the result? Does it loop through all vars of positions_used?

Comment: alert (position_id); popup "E2" "A3" etc.... so is working i guess